Flutter Web App Shows Grey Screen with Minified Error Code
I am developing a Flutter web application and have encountered an issue where the entire screen turns grey and the console shows the error: "Another exception was thrown: Instance of 'minified:jI'". This occurs in the production build as indicated by the "minified" segment in the URL. Here is the context of my implementation:
code
class StoreScreen1 extends StatefulWidget {
  final String uid; // Accept the user ID as a parameter

  StoreScreen1({required this.uid});

  @override
  _StoreScreen1State createState() => _StoreScreen1State();
}

class _StoreScreen1State extends State<StoreScreen1> with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  late TabController _tabController;
  TextEditingController searchController = TextEditingController();
  String _searchQuery = '';


  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _tabController = TabController(length: 3, vsync: this);
    searchController.addListener(_onSearchChanged);
  }

  void _onSearchChanged() {
    setState(() {
      _searchQuery = searchController.text;
    });
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    searchController.removeListener(_onSearchChanged);
    searchController.dispose();
    _tabController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  Stream<List<PetMarket>> _fetchPetsStream(String status) {
    return FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection('petMarketPet')
        .where('uid', isEqualTo: widget.uid) // Use the dynamic uid passed to the screen
        .where('status', isEqualTo: status)
        .snapshots()
        .map((snapshot) {
      return snapshot.docs.map((document) {
        var petData = document.data() as Map<String, dynamic>;
        return PetMarket(
          title: petData['title'] ?? '',
          date: (petData['date'] as Timestamp?)?.toDate() ?? DateTime.now(),
          location: petData['location'] ?? '',

          serviceType: petData['serviceType'] ?? '',
          imageUrl: List<String>.from(petData['imageUrl'] ?? []),
   
          paymentId: petData['paymentId'] ?? '',
          country: '',
          actuallocation: '',
        );
      }).toList()
        ..sort((a, b) => b.date.compareTo(a.date)); // Sort by date
    });
  }

  List<PetMarket> filterPets(String query, List<PetMarket> pets) {
    return pets.where((pet) {
      final locationMatch = pet.location.toLowerCase().contains(query.toLowerCase());
      final breedTypeMatch = pet.breedType.toLowerCase().contains(query.toLowerCase());
      final animalTypeMatch = pet.animalType.toLowerCase().contains(query.toLowerCase());
      return locationMatch || breedTypeMatch || animalTypeMatch;
    }).toList();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return DefaultTabController(
      length: 3,
      child: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(

          title: Text('User Ads', style: TextStyle(color:  Colors.white )),
          leading: IconButton(
            icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_back, color:  Colors.white ),
            onPressed: () {
              Navigator.pop(context);
            },
          ),
          bottom: TabBar(
            controller: _tabController,
            tabs: [
              Tab(text: 'Published'),
              Tab(text: 'Unpublished'),
              Tab(text: 'await'),
            ],
          ),
        ),
        body: TabBarView(
          controller: _tabController,
          children: [
            _buildPetList('published'),
            _buildPetList('unpublished'),
            _buildPetList('await'),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget _buildPetList(String status) {
    return Column(
      children: [
        Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
          child: TextField(
            controller: searchController,
            decoration: InputDecoration(
              hintText: 'Search ads...',
              border: OutlineInputBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8.0)),
              suffixIcon: Icon(Icons.search),
            ),
          ),
        ),
        Expanded(
          child: StreamBuilder<List<PetMarket>>(
            stream: _fetchPetsStream(status),
            builder: (context, snapshot) {
              if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
                return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
              } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
                return Center(child: Text('Error: ${snapshot.error}'));
              } else if (!snapshot.hasData || snapshot.data!.isEmpty) {
                return Center(child: Text('No ads found'));
              }

              List<PetMarket> filteredPets = filterPets(_searchQuery, snapshot.data!);

              return ListView.builder(
                itemCount: filteredPets.length,
                itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                  return Card(
                    child: ListTile(
                      title: Text(filteredPets[index].title),
                      subtitle: Text(filteredPets[index].location),
                      trailing: Text('${filteredPets[index].currency} ${filteredPets[index].price}'),
                      onTap: () {
                        // Navigate to the detailed view
                      },
                    ),
                  );
                },
              );
            },
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}

in url also show "minified"

And the whole page is showing under a grey box. How can I fix it?
